# How can I pass a buttonClick to a Function on another Page?

Tags: function, flutter, arguments, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to pass a simple buttonpress to performe something in another class. The point is to use one page for several different functions, instead of having one page for every function.

Right now the navigation to the textDeclaration-page works fine, but I can't get the right function do do its job.

If I press the First Button, the info from FirstButton Widget should display on the textDeclaration page, and if I press the Second Button, the info from SecondButton Widget should pop up on the displayText-page.

Main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'homePage.dart';

void main()=>runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

HomePage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'textDeclaration.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Function buttonChoice;

  Widget outlineButton(String buttonName) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 60.0,
      width: 225.0,
      child: OutlineButton(
          highlightedBorderColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          child: Text(buttonName,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: 
FontWeight.bold)),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: 2.0,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            navigate(buttonName, buttonChoice);
          }),
    );
  }

  void navigate(String buttonName, Function buttonChoice) {
    setState(() {
      Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => TextDeclaration(
                buttonName: buttonName,
                buttonChoice: buttonChoice,
              )));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('HOME PAGE')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            outlineButton('First Button'),
            outlineButton('Second Button'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

textDeclarationPage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextDeclaration extends StatefulWidget {
  final String buttonName;
  final Function buttonChoice;

  TextDeclaration({this.buttonName, this.buttonChoice});

  @override
  _TextDeclarationState createState() => _TextDeclarationState();
}

class _TextDeclarationState extends State<TextDeclaration> {
  String buttonName = "";

  buttonChoice(String buttonName) {
    if (buttonName == 'First Button') {
      firstButton(buttonName);
    } else if (buttonName == 'Second Button') {
      secondButton(buttonName);
    }
  }

  Widget firstButton(buttonName) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Button'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 200.0,
          width: 200.0,
          child: Center(child: Text('First Button Text')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget secondButton(buttonName) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Button'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 200.0,
          width: 200.0,
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Second Button Text'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
      child: buttonChoice(buttonName),
    );
  }
}
```

The code runs, but the functions from the different buttons won't work.

Any help at all would be great since I've been stuck with this for a very long time now. Thanks.

Comment: Try to pass another 'FirstButton' parameter, I think you're missing another parameter on the outline function, you're only passing the buttonName, there is buttonFunction too

Comment: And since you are veryfing by the String you're adding, change the "Function" buttonChoice to a "String"

Comment: If I got it right, you want to call a function in your main class when you tap on a button in your Second page?

Comment: I'm trying Fellipe, but its going so so

Comment: @nick.tdr. I uppdated my question, hoping to clearify my problem. Thanks for your time.